# Browser EventListenerList Implementation

Tags: javascript, dom, browser, dom-events

Are there any browsers that implement the DOM3 EventListenerList interface?

http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20010823/events.html#Events-EventListenerList

Comment: See my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810534/have-any-browsers-implemented-the-dom3-eventlistenerlist/7814692#7814692

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not currently supported in any browser.

See **[Advanced event registration models](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html)**