# How to remove event of an element that was declared by an anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, anonymous-function

Example code:

```
element.addEventListener('click',function () {
  this.style.backgroundColor = '#cc0000'
  //after element was clicked once what to do here to remove this event ?
},false)
```

And where to do it, is it possible directly in function where I put the comment?

Comment: Related question on getting a list of event listeners: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810534/have-any-browsers-implemented-the-dom3-eventlistenerlist/7814692#7814692

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you add an event with `addEventListener()` you must have a reference to that function available to be able to subsequently remove it.

With an anonymous function that's only possible with `arguments.callee`, and then only while you're within the function itself:

```
element.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = '#cc0000';
    this.removeEventListener('click', arguments.callee);
}, false);
```

but note that this isn't legal in ES5 "strict mode".

Hence it would just be better to give your callback a name and then use that in the call to `removeEventLister()`:

```
element.addEventListener('click', function cb() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = '#cc0000';
    this.removeEventListener('click', cb);
}, false);
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/RsaVE/

Comment: But I wonder if they would really delete `arguments.callee` functionality from the browsers, it can be deprecated for tens of years and work like a charm.

Comment: @rsk82 it's already deleted if the code declares `"use strict";`

Answer (score 2):

Not truly anonymous anymore, but here is the best I can come up with (using a closure):

```
(function(){
  var handler = function(){
    this.style.backgroundColor = '#cc0000'
    element.removeEventListener('click', handler, false);
  };
  element.addEventListener('click', handler, false);
})();
```

Edit:  +1 for Alnitak's revised answer - it's a little more concise than this one.