# Dynamically change YouTube player size with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dynamic, youtube, userscripts

I want YouTube to fill my browser window completely, without removing the comments/playlists/whatever.

I made the following script that works perfectly (ignoring some details I'll fix later) whenever I resize the window. It doesn't (fully) work when the page gets loaded or when I use the maximize button. How can I make it also work in those 2 situations?

I noticed there's some other script on YouTube that changes the style of the `<video>` tag dynamically, can I remove that script or make sure my script runs after that one?

The (user)script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        My Fancy New Userscript
// @namespace   http://your.homepage/
// @version     0.1
// @description enter something useful
// @author      You
// @match       http://www.youtube.com/*
// @match       https://www.youtube.com/*
// @match       http://youtube.com/*
// @match       https://youtube.com/*
// @grant       none
// @run-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript==

var addEvent = function(elem, type, eventHandle) {
    if (elem == null || typeof(elem) == 'undefined') return;
    if ( elem.addEventListener ) {
        elem.addEventListener( type, eventHandle, false );
    } else if ( elem.attachEvent ) {
        elem.attachEvent( "on" + type, eventHandle );
    } else {
        elem["on"+type]=eventHandle;
    }
};

var resizer = function() {
    var clientWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth || window.innerWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
    var clientHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight || window.innerHeight || document.body.clientHeight;
    var player = document.getElementById("player");
    var playerAPI = document.getElementById("player-api-legacy") || document.getElementById("player-api");
    var videoContainer = player;

    var html5container = document.getElementsByTagName("video");
    console.log(html5container);
    html5container[0].style.width = 100 + "%";
    html5container[0].style.height = 100 + "%";

    player.removeAttribute("class");
    playerAPI.style.width = clientWidth + "px";
    playerAPI.style.height = clientHeight + "px";
}

addEvent(window, "load", resizer);
addEvent(window, "resize", resizer);
```

It's ugly, but it's for personal use only...

PS: Please don't suggest any jQuery stuff, it's not needed/desired.
PPS: It only needs to run on Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution here:
[Detect element style change in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566346/detect-element-style-change-in-chrome)

It seems to be reliable through any type of resizing.