# removeEventListner not working

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have recreated my problem in the smallest amount of code I could think of Lol

Basically, I have an iFrame that uses `addEventListener` using data that the user has posted though a form. It works well, until the user posts again, and then 2 EventListeners are present. I have tried using `removeEventListener` but this is not working in this case.

Here is what I have done to recreate the problem:

## TESTbuffer.php

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<script>
function startListener() {
    parent.document.removeEventListener('mouseup',outputInput,false);
    parent.document.addEventListener('mouseup',outputInput,false);
}
function outputInput() {
    console.log('<?php echo $_POST['input']; ?>');
}
</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY onload='startListener()'>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

## TESTparent.php

```
<iframe name="bufferiframe" id="bufferiframe"></iframe>
<form name="Test" method="POST" action="TESTbuffer.php" target="bufferiframe">
    <input type="text" name="input">
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

Here's what happens if you follow these steps:

1. Enter 'hello' and click 'Go'
2. click anywhere on the screen, then 'hello' appears in the console.
3. Enter 'bye' and click 'Go'
4. click anywhere on the screen, then 'hello' and 'bye' appears in the console.

I have also tried the function as:

```
function startListener() {
    parent.document.addEventListener('mouseup',outputInput,false);
    parent.document.removeEventListener('mouseup',outputInput,false);
    parent.document.addEventListener('mouseup',outputInput,false);
}
```

with the same result

Any help appreciated :D

Comment: Where exactly are we supposed to type "hello" and click "Go" ?

Comment: in the form lol, within TESTparent.php

Comment: Any problem clarification that involves the expression 'lol' worries me, and implies rather strongly (if not literally) that you're not taking our attempts to help seriously.

Comment: @Stretch - so you want us to recreate your site and your problem somewhere ?

Comment: @adeneo That's what most users who come here want us to do, yes.

Comment: I take all answers seriously, just thought it was funny that he hadn't read the question

Comment: The problem here is that your `TESTbuffer.php` page reloads with each form submission. When the page reloads, the newly-reloaded page has a brand new JavaScript environment, which means a brand new `outputInput`. You're trying to remove the `outputInput` of the *new* page, which is differnet fro the `outputInput` of the *old* page, which has vanished.

Comment: @aspillers - Ah I see now ... So is there a way I can remove it?

Comment: @Stretch I'm not sure -- which is why I didnt post an answer. Do JavaScript properties on `parent` persist between reloads? If so, you might try saving a reference to the function as a property on `parent`, and then removing that function as a listener on reload (and then, of course, saving the *new* function as a `parent` property).

Comment: @Stretch - Yes. If you implement the event using jQuery, you can flush all events, including the one you added, with `.off()`.

Comment: @Blufire - I'm trying to avoid using jQuery for this project

Comment: @Stretch - The best, and possibly only way to do it in this case would be to flush all events from the document. Sadly, plain JS has no such function, while jQuery does.

Comment: Wait a second... you could, as a dirty hack, copy your main element. This would copy everything inside it, but not the events attached to it, thus removing all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to flush all of the `mouseup` events from the document. Here, you have 2 options.

Option 1: uses jQuery, but is clean:

Use

```
function startListener() {
    $(parent.document).off('mouseup');
    $(parent.document).on('mouseup', function () {
        // do event handler stuff here
    });
}
```

into `TESTbuffer.php`.

Option 2: doesn't use jQuery, but is dirty:

Use this ([written by me, with no help whatsoever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469881/javascript-remove-all-event-listeners-of-specific-type)):

```
var el = parent.document.body,
    elClone = el.cloneNode(true);

el.parentNode.replaceChild(elClone, el);
```

in `TESTbuffer.php`, and attach your events to the `body` instead of the document:

```
parent.document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', outputInput, false);
```