# How to find where event handler added?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How can I found the trigger codes if there is a button which can do an event but it seems like has no set event handler? 
For example widget toolbox buttons in bootsrap templates. The buttons have just a class but they are working well.

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="collapse" data-original-title="" title=""></a>
```

Where are the codes of this collapse function?

Comment: "there is no any set event operation" Have you clicked a submit button?

Comment: That's kind of XY problem, you'd have better to search for why any event is bound or explain why this is an issue for you. Maybe your button submit a FORM or whatever...

Comment: Key word here is "bootstrap" which is what is adding the "collapse" functionality. See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/ if you're using version 4 or http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.0.3/docs/javascript/#collapse for version 3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The actual code to animate the collapse is in this scss [collapse transition](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/e57a2f244ba8446fffe71847e6a58b18f7b2d541/scss/_transitions.scss#L11-L22)

```scss
.collapse {
  &:not(.show) {
    display: none;
  }
}

.collapsing {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  @include transition($transition-collapse);
}
```

...and the actual transition is set [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/29bd5e32186b2d56b7b35a09597bfed6636d66c9/scss/_variables.scss#L246).

There is javascript that toggles the class states between the following states as documented [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/6e2a823a44063af96749d54560808656e007c2a8/js/src/collapse.js#L43-L48):

1. `.collapse` - Closed state of the "dropdown" component and the query to know what elements to apply collapse toggle logic to.
2. `.collapsing` - Interim state between closed and open in which the css transition is applied.
3. `.collapse.show` - Open state of the "dropdown"

I assume that javascript logic is [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/6e2a823a44063af96749d54560808656e007c2a8/js/src/collapse.js#L119-L148) for showing the "dropdown" when the `[data-toggle]=collapse` element is clicked in open state. Then the logic for hiding the "dropdown" is [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/6e2a823a44063af96749d54560808656e007c2a8/js/src/collapse.js#L203-L257). The show/hide logic is only toggling the css classes to correspond to the states above, which then triggers the css transition above.

### Notice the toggle of class on the "dropdown" between clicks

[image: tets]

Comment: This answer is awesome! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

As @A. Wolff said, the default action of a button is to submit a form, which will lead you to another web page, specified on that form.

Have a look at the form element described at [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type), you can basically
reach the same behaviour using the [button](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_button_test) element.

If you want to inspect what events are attached to your button, you can right click it and see the elements inspector.

[image: On the image, the Google Chrome's element inspector]

If there are no events attached then nothing will be shown, also, if this button belongs to a form, the default action is not considered as a Javascript Event.

If you want to remove all listeners maybe you should take a look to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469881/javascript-remove-all-event-listeners-of-specific-type)