# JS click event firing before it can be removed by code above the trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is more of a statement and wondering if anyone has experienced this than a question, but here goes. Consider the following code using JQuery:

```
<input type="submit"
       value="Delete"
       onclick="return doesUserConfirmDelete();" />
<script type="text/javascript">
  function doesUserConfirmDelete()
  {
    return confirm("Do you really want to delete this entry?\n\n" +
                   "Click \'OK\' to delete this entry;\n\n" +
                   "otherwise, click \'Cancel.\'");
  }

  var delBtn = $('input[value="Delete"]');
  console.info(delBtn[0]);
  delBtn.removeAttr('onclick');
  // attempted adding the following, but nothing changed:
  delBtn.removeProp('onclick');
  delBtn.prop('onclick', null);
  delBtn[0].onclick = null;
  // end attempts for naught
  delBtn.off('click');
  delBtn.click();
</script>
```

When I run the above code in Chrome, the things that happen, in order, are:

- Confirm box is shown (even though the `onclick` was supposedly removed)
- I click cancel
- `console.info` message prints to console.

What is going on here? How do I remove the click events from the button and click it so that there's no confirmation dialog?

Comment: Nullify the `onclick` property, that's where the listener actually lives. AFAIK `.off` removes listeners added by using `.on` only.

Comment: I quickly tried adding `delBtn.removeProp('onclick');` after the `delBtn.removeAttr('onclick');` call, but nothing changed. Edit - Also tried with `delBtn.prop('onclick', null);`. Nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit"
       value="Delete"
       onclick="return doesUserConfirmDelete();" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
  function doesUserConfirmDelete()
  {
    return confirm("Do you really want to delete this entry?\n\n" +
                   "Click \'OK\' to delete this entry;\n\n" +
                   "otherwise, click \'Cancel.\'");
  }

  var delBtn = $('input[value="Delete"]');
  console.info(delBtn[0]);
  delBtn.removeAttr('onclick');
  delBtn.off('click');
  delBtn.click();
</script>
```

If you want to avoid button to be clickable you can use prevent default.Is this what you asked? Can you give more details if this didn't answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. No, I need the button to be clickable, but I want to remove the confirmation dialog that's being shown by the `onclick` event.

Comment: If you don't to show the confirmation dialog, then you can remove it right?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/19470348/493807

I just needed to clone the element after removing the `onclick` attribute, and click the clone.

```
delBtn.removeAttr('onclick');
var clone = delBtn.clone();
clone.replaceAll(delBtn);
clone.click();
```