# Range Input freezing on IOS in Divi on WordPress

Tags: ios, wordpress

This incredibly strange behaviour has cropped up and I haven't been able to figure out what is causing it. Has anyone else ran into this before?

https://conquer-local.websitepro.hosting/?page_id=177

If you load this page on iOS and try to move the range value it won't let you slide to completion - instead it locks up after a cm or two.

This example from codepen works properly on iOS and other wordpress sites I've tried with a basic input seem to work so I'm lost as to what Divi is doing here.

https://codepen.io/abissonnette/full/mMwWZE/

```
<input id="range" type="range" min=0 max=150 value=0 />
```

Answer (score 0):

Aha! Relatively simple solution. It seems as though Divi adds an extra script onto Range inputs. This causes them to freeze in ios.

Simply calling unbind on your ranges before added other methods should fix this:

```
jQuery('input[type="range"]').unbind();
```

Vanilla js might be tougher - it looks like you have to mess around in the dom or employ a super hacky solution: [Remove All Event Listeners of Specific Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469881/remove-all-event-listeners-of-specific-type)