# Google Street View JavaScript API disable keyboard zooming

Tags: google-maps, google-street-view

How can I disable keyboard shortcut zooming in Google Street View?

According to the [JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#MapOptions), setting `keyboardShortcuts: false` for `google.maps.MapOptions` should prevent any control via the keyboard, but 
zooming still works using the `+` and `-` keyboard shortcuts.

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  center: fenway,
  zoom: 14,
  keyboardShortcuts: false /* should prevent +/- zooming */
});
```

Here is an [example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z8Ln8v6t/).

Edit: as geocodezip points out, `keyboardShortcuts` is only an option for the overhead map. `google.maps.StreetViewPanoramaOptions` doesn't have these options. Could the keyboard shortcuts be turned off manually by disabling the events?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - nice to have you. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help keeping Stack Overflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer. Please paste here the code you have right now.

Comment: `keyboardShortcuts: false` controls zooming for the map.  The StreetViewPanorama doesn't seem to have the equivalent control.

Comment: @geocodezip good point. Could the shortcuts still be disabled manually using preventDefault or something similar on the key events?

Answer (score 2):

The API doesn't seem to allow preventing Google Maps from registering the keyboard event handlers, but you can [intercept the events and stop them propagating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469881/remove-all-event-listeners-of-specific-type):

```js
window.addEventListener(
  'keydown',
  (event) => {
    if (
      (
        // Change or remove this condition depending on your requirements.
        event.key === 'ArrowUp' || // Move forward
        event.key === 'ArrowDown' || // Move forward
        event.key === 'ArrowLeft' || // Pan left
        event.key === 'ArrowRight' || // Pan right
        event.key === '+' || // Zoom in
        event.key === '=' || // Zoom in
        event.key === '_' || // Zoom out
        event.key === '-' // Zoom out
      ) &&
      !event.metaKey &&
      !event.altKey &&
      !event.ctrlKey
    ) {
      event.stopPropagation()
    };
  },
  { capture: true },
);
```

The above will block moving, panning, and zooming via the keyboard, but you can adjust if if you just want to block some shortcuts. The key is the `capture` option for `addEventListener()`, which gives this event hander higher precedence.