# Ionic 4 - Hardware back button disable, then enable back button to default

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I want to disable hardware back button on certain condition, after that i want the back button to act as default.

Answer (score 1):

reference from my answer of this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55274992/ionic-4-prevent-disable-device-hardware-backbutton)

i found better way to do avoid back button device, and make disable back on whatever page do you want

just make service.ts

```
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DisableBackService {
  // page disable back button
  private blackLists: string[] = ['/tab/wall', '/event-list', '/tutorial', '/offline-message'];

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    // call every have change page
    this.router.events.subscribe((ev) => {
      if (ev instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        const blackList = this.blackLists.find(el => ev.url.includes(el));
        if (blackList) {
          this.disableBack();
        } else {
          this.enableBack();
        }
      }
    });
  }

  private logger() {
    console.log('disable back button');
  }

  disableBack() {
    document.addEventListener('backbutton', this.logger, false);
  }

  enableBack() {
    document.removeEventListener('backbutton', this.logger, false);
  }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you very much for this. It helped greatly when used with fancybox3