# How do I prevent right-click on Puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer

I'd like to prevent users from right-clicking on a Chromium instance generated in Puppeteer. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to do it is to register [a function that will run before opening any new page](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluateonnewdocumentpagefunction-args):

```
await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => 
    document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault()) 
);
```

Of course the target page could remove and/or reassign that event listener. So another way is to wait for the page to load (or wait for some selector) and create event listener again:

```
await page.evaluate(() =>
    document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault())
);
```

Or you could do an even more devious thing and hijack `document.addEventListener` to disallow adding `contextmenu` event listeners at all:

```
await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => { 

      document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault())

      const realAddEventListener = document.addEventListener;

      document.addEventListener = function(type, listener){
          type === 'contextmenu' || realAddEventListener.apply(this, arguments);
      };
  }
);
```

*(based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45174013/2715393) and its comment)*