# Convert jquery unbind to vanillajs

Tags: typescript

I try to change this jquery

```
$('.myOwnClass').removeClass('myOwnClass').unbind('dblclick');
```

for use in vanillajs / typescript. I can remove the class with the following code. But the unbind I do not know so far

```
const myList = document.querySelector('.myOwnClass') as HTMLElement;
    myList.classList.remove('myOwnClass');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [.removeEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)

didn't use a lot of jQuery but from my understanding it's almost the same but using the Dom's events mechanism

Comment: Thank you. But what is the second parameter ov removeEventListener? In jQuery I use no additional information to remove the dblclick

Comment: You need to add the event handler (the one you used in `.bind`).  If you're don't have it, you can always `coneNode` https://stackoverflow.com/a/19470348