# Can't remove keydown event listener programtically

Tags: javascript

The <kbd>CTRL + e</kbd> combination on is quite annoying, I'm need to remove the keydown handler.

From chrome the event listener is on textarea:

[image]

So I created a script and tested it in devtools:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("textarea")).forEach(e => {
    const ev = getEventListeners(e)
    if (ev['keydown']) {
        console.log(ev['keydown'])
        ev['keydown'].forEach((row) => {
            e.removeEventListener('keydown', row.listener, false)
        })
    }
})
```

But the event listener is still there, what was wrong?

**EDIT**

As @wahoowa suggested, this worked partially, <kbd>CTRL + E</kbd> no longer creates the backtick on github.

But it doesn't do the default action on Mac as well. The default action is to jump to the end of line, how can I do the default behavior when <kbd>CTRL + E</kbd> is pressed?

```
document.querySelectorAll("textarea").forEach(e => {
    e.addEventListener("keydown", ev => {
        if (ev.key == 'e' && ev.ctrlKey) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            ev.stopPropagation();
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Maybe, you could try a Hard refresh. To do that, press the key combo `ctrl + F5`

Comment: probably because the event is attached to a parent element, as shown in the screenshot no keydown event is attached directly to the textarea (most are in the document)

Comment: @sney2002 I've changed the selector query to `*`, which will remove all event listeners, but still didn't work

Comment: @daisy that returns all document descendants, but the event seems to be attached to the document itself, and * doesn't include "document" as you can test with `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("*")).find(element=>element===document)`. you must remove the event directly from document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of removing it, you could add an event listener to all `textarea` elements to prevent the default behavior and also stop propagation of the event to parent elements.

```
document.querySelectorAll("textarea").forEach(e => {
    e.addEventListener("keydown", ev => {
        ev.preventDefault();
        ev.stopPropagation();
    })
})
```

Note that this is solution to your scenario, but it does not answer your initial question of how to remove an event listener. If there were other `keydown` event listeners added to the `textarea` elements, those would not be removed. In order to actually remove the event listeners, you can look at these other questions:

- [Remove All Event Listeners of Specific Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469881/remove-all-event-listeners-of-specific-type)
- [Javascript/DOM: How to remove all event listeners of a DOM object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386300/javascript-dom-how-to-remove-all-event-listeners-of-a-dom-object)