# Cannot disable mousedown event of Konva

Tags: javascript, jquery, disable, mousedown, konva

I am trying to disable the mousedown event with javascript. I am trying to modify a project of github so I don't know exactly the event function name. I can disable it through firefox,chrome tool but I cannot disable it programmaticaly. I have tried

```
$('.konvajs-content').off('mousedown');
$(".konvajs-content").onmousedown = null;
$(".konvajs-content").on("mousedown", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopImmediatePropagation();
   e.returnValue = false;
     });
```

It seems like another event is created but the event from Konva is not disabled.
[This is the image of my console log and the event I want to disable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bv6jI.png)

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72263817/2495207), making a little change you can desable/delete the `mousedown` event only:

```js
      $(".class1").on("mousedown", () => {
        console.log("mousedown");
      });

      function deleteEvent() {
        const a = document.getElementsByClassName("class1")[0];
        const regex = new RegExp(/jQuery\d*/);
        for (const key in a) {
          if (regex.test(key)) {
            delete a[key].events.mousedown;
            return;
          }
        }
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <button class="class1">button</button>
    <button class="class2" onclick="deleteEvent()">remove event from button</button>
```