# How can I get the JS code of an existing HTML element?

Tags: javascript, dom, firefox-addon

I wonder if there's any way to get the JS code of an existing HTML element using any existing method. I am trying to print the code generator of any DOM element, so when the user clicks on any HTML element of the webpage, a message will be shown with the source code to create that element in Javascript.

For example, I have a Div created:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.style.border = "1px dotted red";
div.onmouseover=function(){div.style.color = "red"};
div.innerHTML = "I'm the div";
```

And then I was trying to obtain the source code, but:

```
document.body.appendChild(div.innerHTML);
```

This option only writes the textual content: "I'm the div". SO I tryed:

```
document.body.appendChild(div.outerHTML);
```

But it writes the HTML code without the onmouseover function: "I'm the div"

What I really need is to show this code (or something similar):

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.style.border = "1px dotted red";
div.onmouseover=function(){div.style.color = "red"};
div.innerHTML = "I'm the div";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x2zJs/

Do you have any idea where can I start reading?
Thanks a lot,

Comment: What about the HTML elements which are just in the HTML file?

Comment: So you want to generate the JavaScript code that would generate that element?

Comment: Yes Chevi, I want to generate the code of any selected dom element

Comment: You can't get the code that was used to make the element. You can make something that generates code that would create a element like the one you click, would this be okay?

Comment: @gal007 I hope my answer helped you with getting the code of the events. Is there any other issue you need for your addon?

Answer (score 2):

### outerHTML

`outerHTML` is a good choice with several limitations:

1. today (2014) [you can't get attached listeners natively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623118/inspect-attached-event-handlers-for-any-dom-element)
2. [outerHTML](http://domparsing.spec.whatwg.org/#outerhtml) uses [html node serialization](http://domparsing.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-serialize-html), which uses uses [xml attributes serialization algorithm](http://domparsing.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-serialize-xml-attributes)

In other words, IDL attributes are ignored, only content attributes are serialized.

Events by **IDL attributes** are coded as

```
div.onmouseover=function(){div.style.color = "red"};
div.addEventListener("mouseover",function() {div.style.backgroundColor="blue";});
```

See more about [events](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/webappapis.html#events)

Whereas events by **content attributes** are coded as

```
div.setAttribute("onmouseover","this.style.color='red'");
```

Using content attribute, the outerHTML looks like this:

```
<div onmouseover="this.style.color='red'" style="border: 1px dotted red;">
  I'm the div
</div>
```

See [your updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x2zJs/1/).

Long story short, there are two ways to code a handler:

```
var setColor = function(e) { e.target.style.color = "red"; }
div.onmouseover = setColor; // IDL, not seen by outerHTML
div.setAttribute("onmouseover","setColor(event)"); // content, seen by outerHTML
```

### eventListenerList

If you want to retrieve the IDL events somehow, nice proposed `eventListenerList` property was removed from DOM3 spec proposal (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810534/have-any-browsers-implemented-the-dom3-eventlistenerlist)).

If you want to write a firefox addon (something like code inspector), extending the Element.prototype will do the trick (as I tested, it works in Firefox, Chrome and Opera, it doesn't work in IE7):

```
(function() {
  Element.prototype.eventListenerList = {};
  Element.prototype._addEventListener = Element.prototype.addEventListener;
  Element.prototype.addEventListener = function(a,b,c) {
    this._addEventListener(a,b,c);
    if(!this.eventListenerList[a]) this.eventListenerList[a] = [];
    this.eventListenerList[a].push(b);
  };
})();
```

To be precise, you should also override the `Element.prototype.removeEventListener` to remove the event from the custom EventListenerList.

Now you can add the events by `addEventListener` as usual:

```
function handlerA() { alert('a'); }
function handlerB() { alert('b'); }
function handlerC() { alert('c'); }

// attach handlers
div.onclick = handlerC;
div.addEventListener("click",handlerA);
div.addEventListener("click",handlerB);
```

...and to display the code of the listeners. I will do this for `onclick` event, in your code you should iterate through every possible event. Don't forget the eventual `onclick` listener (you can't override `Element.prototype.onclick` because it is non-configurable property):

```
var clickListeners = "";
if(div.eventListenerList.click)
div.eventListenerList.click.forEach(function(f) {
  clickListeners+= f.toString();
});
if(div.onclick) clickListeners+= div.onclick.toString();
alert(clickListeners);
```

See and test [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Su9AJ/1/). Put these pieces together as it suits to your addon.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built-in that will give you what you want, try the "aardvark bookmarklet" it has a somewhat nice js generating command.
http://karmatics.com/aardvark/bookmarklet.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could wrap the creation of your `div` element with a function and then parse and print contents of that function.

Following is a working example (tested in Chrome, Firefox and Safari):
Also here http://jsfiddle.net/smnh/x2zJs/2/

```
function createDiv() {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.border = "1px dotted red";
    div.onmouseover = function() {div.style.color = "red"};
    div.innerHTML = "I'm the div";
    div.creationString = getFunctionContnet(createDiv); // noprint
    return div; // noprint
}

function getFunctionContnet(func) {
    var regExp = /function[^(]*\([^)]*\)[^{]*{(?:\s*\n)?(\s*)([\s\S]*)(?:\n\s*)}/,
        match,
        indention, indentionRE,
        noprintRE = /\/\/.*noprint.*/,
        content = null,
        lines, i;

    match = regExp.exec(func.toString());

    if (match !== null) {
        indention = match[1];
        content = match[2];

        lines = content.split("\n");

        // if first line of the function is indented,
        // remove that indention from all function lines.
        if (typeof indention !== "undefined") {
            indentionRE = new RegExp("^" + indention);
            for (i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                if (indentionRE.test(lines[i])) {
                    lines[i] = lines[i].substr(indention.length);
                }
            }
        }

        // don't print lines with "// noprint"
        for (i = lines.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (noprintRE.test(lines[i])) {
                lines.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }

        content = lines.join("\n");
    }

    return content;
}
```

Here if you create your `div` and log the `creationString` you will get the text of the function.

```
div = createDiv();
console.log(div.creationString);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the creation of the elements you could ensure that each element is created in it's own separate function. Then a simple function can get the function body.

```
function createElement1() {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.border = "1px dotted red";
    div.onmouseover=function(){div.style.color = "red"};
    div.innerHTML = "I'm the div";
}

function getFunctionBody(func) {
    var functionText = func.toString();
    return functionText.slice(functionText.indexOf("{") + 1, functionText.lastIndexOf("}"));
}
```

Here's a working example. http://jsfiddle.net/C5b7n/